# How to pass a data from a TableView? (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView`, which contains a Source.

UIViewController = `TableViewController.cs`

UITableView = `_table`

Source = `TableSource.cs`

Inside my `TableSource` I have the `RowSelected` method, but I want to pass the `RowSelected` value to the `TableViewController`, so I can perform actions based on conditionals with `SetRightBarButtonItem`.

My question is, how can I pass the variable from the selected row in `_table` to `TableViewController` which contains the `RightBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go. One might be to pass a reference of the ViewController to your source like this: `var source = new Source(parentController);`.

Your datasource needs a new constructor that takes that parameter. When ever the row selection changed you can than operate on the controller.

Another one might be to create an event inside your source. Every time your selection changed you fire that event that will be handled on your controller.